# Regex match for a specific pattern excluding a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have sample string as :

1. `'&label=20:01:27&tooltext=abc\&|\|cba&value=6|59|58|89&color=ff0000|00ffff'`
2. `'&label=20:01:27&tooltext=abc\&|\|cba&value=6|59|58|89'`

My objective is to select the text from '`tooltext=`' till the first occurrence of '`&`' which is not preceded by `\\`. I'm using the following regex :

```
/(tooltext=)(.*)([^\\])(&)/
```

and the `.match()` function.
It is working fine for the second string but for the first string it is selecting upto the last occurrence of '`&`' not preceded by `\\`.

```
var a = '&label=20:01:27&tooltext=abc\&|\|cba&value=6|59|58|89&color=ff0000|00ffff',
b = a.match(/(tooltext=)(.*)([^\\])(&)(.*[^\\]&)?/i)
```

result,

```
b = ["tooltext=abc\&|\|cba&value=40|84|40|62&", "tooltext=", "abc\&|\|cba&value=40|84|40|6", "2", "&"]
```

But what i need is:

```
b = ["tooltext=abc&||cba&", "tooltext=", "abc&||cb", "a", "&"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/tooltext=(.*?\\&)*.*?&/
```

**[[`Regex Demo`]](https://regex101.com/r/qQ3nH7/1)**

and to always found a non-escaped `&`:

```
/tooltext=(.*?\\&)*.*?[^\\]&/
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @shA.t - I'm afraid but it is matching the following text 
'value=66,34|77,99&tooltext=av\&,\,|\&\|,^'
But ideally it should not because it does not have non escaped &

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regex is matching all the way to the *last* `&` instead of the first one without a backslash in front of it. Try adding the `?` operator to make it match as small as possible like so:

`/(tooltext=)(.*?)([^\\])(&)/`

And if you just want the text between `tooltext=` and `&`, try this to make it return the important part as the matched group:

`/tooltext=(.*?[^\\])&/`